# handle commas and quotes in cell values of CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am using python's csv reader but some columns are failing to process because they contain a comma or quote.

How can you get the correct string?

For example one cell says:

```
"['one', 'two', 'three']"
```

but it gives me:

`"['one'`

```
if os.path.exists(CSV_PATH):
    with open(CSV_PATH, 'r') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
        field_list = []
        for row in reader:
            if not field_list:
                field_list = [c for c in row]
                continue

            d = dict.fromkeys(field_list)
            for header, col in zip(field_list, row):
                print(col)
```

Comment: instead of `field_list = [c for c in row]` you can write `field_list = row` to get the same result.

Comment: if you use `quotechar='"'` then it should work correctly.

Comment: You've set `quotechar` to `'|'`, which means that your `"` doesn't do any column grouping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [escapechar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.Dialect.escapechar) attribute with some prefix symbol:

> A one-character string used by the writer to escape the delimiter if quoting is set to QUOTE_NONE and the quotechar if doublequote is False. On reading, the escapechar removes any special meaning from the following character. It defaults to None, which disables escaping.

Also you can use [doublequote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.Dialect.doublequote) attribute with `"` symbol:

> Controls how instances of quotechar appearing inside a field should themselves be quoted. When True, the character is doubled. When False, the escapechar is used as a prefix to the quotechar. It defaults to True.
>
> On output, if doublequote is False and no escapechar is set, Error is raised if a quotechar is found in a field.

Comment: If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will upvote/accept my answer :)